# How to clear cache in picasso?

Tags: java, android, caching, memory, picasso

I am developing an android app.In that app, the server stores the images that is to be displayed in imageView of listview. I use picasso to get image from the server and display in imageview. Though I had uploaded new images in server, only old images are being displayed again. I suspect this is due to cache in picasso.
I used 3 methods to prevent cache:

```
Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(data.get(pos).getFeed_thumb_image()).skipMemoryCache().into(image);

Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(data.get(pos).getFeed_thumb_image()).memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE).into(image);

Picasso.with(context).invalidate(imagePath);
```

But in no result. How can I clear cache in picasso for particular url?

Comment: When you say that old images are displayed again, do you mean after you fully clear the app from memory and return to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try load url with variable like time now:
Calendar urlvar = Calendar.getInstance(); 
int seconds = urlvar.get(Calendar.SECOND);

Then load your url by adding to string: ?urlvar so the final loaded url will be for example example.com/m.png?date it will be cashed but next load the date is changed so the url will change so will not load from cash. Hope ot work

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be implemented in the future, but see the [post of Jake Wharton](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/438#issuecomment-66708967):

> JakeWharton commented on 11 Dec 2014 Current best candidate:

```
picasso.load('http://example.com/')
  .cachePolicy(NO_CACHE, NO_STORE)
  .networkPolicy(NO_CACHE, NO_STORE, OFFLINE)
  .into(imageView);

enum MemoryPolicy {
  NO_CACHE, NO_STORE
}
enum NetworkPolicy {
  NO_CACHE, NO_STORE, OFFLINE
}
```

> This will be what's implemented unless anyone has other thoughts.

Comment: Ideally, his server should correct the cache headers if they allow too much time, though.

Comment: His use of `invalidate` makes me wonder if he's talking about the memory or HTTP client file cache.